# uses-configuration and supports-screens makes app incompatible with all devices?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have published a test app with such manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="false"
    android:reqHardKeyboard="false"
    android:reqKeyboardType="nokeys"
    android:reqNavigation="nonav"
    android:reqTouchScreen="notouch"></uses-configuration>

    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TestManifestAttributesActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I published the app and it is incompatible with all devices, both mine and all of my friends. We have apps with Normal and Large screens, mdpi and hdpi.

[image]

Why is this happening? Why can't I use these attributes at all?

Comment: Did you have any luck? With which settings? Thanks.

Comment: stopped using uses-configuration

Comment: uhm, thanks. I have no *uses-configuration* and still many devices seem to be not compatible, including the one where I tested the app for so long.

Comment: You must have some limiting attributes in the Manifest. What do you have in manifest beside <application> and <uses-sdk>?

Comment: It has been deleted due to duplicate question and/or answer. It's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8985059/540776)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notouch` means the application doesn't require a touch screen
and you are setting `android:reqHardKeyboard="false"`.

Remove the `uses-configuration` tag.

Comment: Hm, I do not want to remove it, but I will try to play with options. Thanks for pointing me.