# Android Market - This application is available to over 0 devices?

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play, device

I have published apk to the Android Market, **activated** and setup for free for all countries.
[image]
Android Market says, my application is not compatible with any of the devices. I can see an application when I access Android Market from the PC browser but I can not download it from any of the Android phone (the same device used to test application before release).

How is that possible if I have just few requirements? I have tested the application on a few quite old devices before upload and it worked.

**Information from the Publishing options:**

```
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.touchscreen

*This application is available to over 0 devices.*
```

[image]

**Information fron the APK tab:**

```
VersionCode: 2
VersionName: 1.0.1
Size: 4.3M
Localized to: default
Permissions: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
Features: android.hardware.screen.portrait, android.hardware.touchscreen
API level: 7-15+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
```

[image]

If it is not strange enough, I have another application at the same account with very similar requirements and it gives me: ***This application is available to over 746 devices***.
[image]
What is going on?

**UPDATE:**

Because many answers suggests something like: *"Just activate your APK..."* I emphasize it again:

**APK is ACTIVATED** (as stated at the beginning of the question and presented on the screenshot above).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My app after an update had was available for 0 devices.

Anyway I found the solution for my case, so you can check if it works for you as well.

my mistake was that I included .jar files in order to add some external libraries and not the respective external class folders. When I removed the .jar files and I just added the class folder then devices became over 700 again.

for example I had the facebook API (an old one, not the current) and I had created a jar file out of it in order to include it like this in my app.
So when I removed the jar files and added the Facebook API projecy (Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add..., the app was OK for the android market.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the case. I was trying to find a time to post it, but you were first. Thank You.

Comment: hi guys. Could you please elaborate on that Jar library issue? What should I do if I **only** have available a JAR file of some 3rd party library, which my app is compiled against? How come this affects the market filtering mechanism?

Comment: Thannku very much. I was suffering the same issue when i was using Graphs Library as Jar https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/   This issue was removed after i added it as library project

Answer (score 37):

Probably your uploaded APK file is not active. You can check this in the APK tab and switch to "Advanced mode". Here you should have 2 categories, "Active" and "Inactive".

Your file is probably in the Inactive category and you can change it by clicking the Activate link that should be behind it.

Comment: It is in Active state. And the link at the right side says: Deactivate.

Comment: Weird, might have something to do with the `android.hardware.screen.portrait` flag. Maybe you can try to disable that in the AndroidManifest.xml file with `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>`.

Comment: I have similar app with portrait flag on and it gives me 697 devices.

Comment: Could be a delay in the update, can't really see what is going wrong. Can you find your app in the Market?

Comment: Yes, I can find it on regular browser as well as device. But when I try to download it to the device it tells me something like: "This application is not compatible ..." even if the device is the one the tests had been done before release.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file as well?

Comment: I have got the same problem like Lukasz. We have tested it on the tablet before release and now after submitting on the market, it says "Not Compatible with your..." Can anyone help?

Comment: @Piro Great answer Piro really helped in our case

Answer (score 2):

For the records, I've found that one *significant* change that solved my case. Full explanation is at [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/android-market/LFGAnPjFJM0/YO4qeUrTc2QJ) on Android Market Product Group.

Quick answer is remove the following `uses-feature` nodes from your manifest if present:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" />
```

Comment: In the future, questions that can be answered the exact same way should be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: do you mean I should have flagged several similar questions, instead of answering to each of them? If so, does it still make sense I flag them now?

Comment: Yes. There are some _rare_ occasions where four questions that can be answered by the same thing are sufficiently different to stand on their own, however it usually means that we've got a few duplicates. Sometimes, they can actually be merged, which really improves the single (original, or best asked) question.

Answer (score 1):

Just activate the app on the APK files tab and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue, and resolved it just following the advice from http://androidforums.com/threads/0-devices-support-my-app-no-compatible-devices-on-play-store.947943/ , which was to change in `build.gradle` line `compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'` to `compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8'` (so more or less general rule can be drawn, that you need to delete `org.apache.(...)` up to the package name and then just double it before semicolon).

I would be glad though, if someone would point me out why it was like that. Looking for the second term in Maven Central through Android Studio returned no results actually, so I doubted at first if it is going to work at all.