# Issue while publishing Android app: "This application is available to over 0 devices"

Tags: android, compatibility, publishing, device

Hello: I note this question has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/q/8212956/936042 but I hope y'all will entertain my question since I am not able to reproduce the solution.

When I upload my APK to the Android market, the message says "available to over 578 devices" (this is before activation). As soon as I begin to make other changes (such as changing the contact email address) the message changes to "This application is available to over 0 devices". I use Eclipse's Export option to created the final, signed APK.

My Android app uses 3 external JARs (http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list). I add them to the project using Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries/Add External JARs.

The solution posted at the link above implicates the use of external JARS, and their being embedded into the APK in some inappropriate manner, as the cause for this issue:

> my mistake was that I included .jar files in order to add some external libraries and not the respective external class folders. When I removed the .jar files and I just added the class folder then devices became over 700 again.

I don't quite follow the above explanation. If someone (especially the original author) could lay it out in greater detail, I'll be very obliged.

Thanks!

PVS

Answer (score 0):

One of the many "solutions" I stumbled onto was to update Eclipse as well as the Android SDK. I didn't change anything in my project - targeting the same API level etc. After everything got updated, my APK is getting loaded fine, and showing support for over 600 devices.

Hope this helps someone.

PVS