# This application is available to over 0 devices?

Tags: android, publish, knapsack-problem

My application is available to over 0 devices
This is output of "aapt dump badging xxx.apk":

```
package: name='xxx' versionCode='5' versionName='1.0'
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'17'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
application-label:'XXX'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='XXX' icon='res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='xxx.SplashActivity'  label='xxx' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen
unless explicitly made optional'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait','one or more activities have     
specified a portrait orientation'
main
other-activities
search
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '160' '240' '320'
native-code: 'junit-4.7.jar'`
```

Any advice? Thanks
Also application activated and published.

Regards,
Dzmitry

Comment: You're shipping a `junit-4.7.jar` file in `lib/` in the apk and that's super wrong - you can see how aapt thinks it's a native code target.

Comment: Duplicate of [Android Market - This application is available to over 0 devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172454/android-market-this-application-is-available-to-over-0-devices)

Comment: thanks, I found solution remove library which use junit and add sources. And all work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delyan is right!
I'm added some library(in lib/ which use a junit-4.7.jar file in lib/) in the apk and that's super wrong - you can see how aapt thinks it's a native code target.
Solution: I removed library which use junit and add sources. And all work now.

Regards Dzmitry.

Answer (score 1):

This is usual in `Google Play`. The `Google Play` won't show all the supported devices immediately. It takes some time may be an hour or even a day to show all the supported devices. So you don't have to worry about that. Check some time later. You will be happy. I faced this too.